# Inserting textarea value in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to insert textarea value into database as when user press enter in textarea that pertucular value before pressing enter btn should be insert in one row.

For example, if I wrote in textarea in this format

```
Monika,
Ritu,
Archana
```

Then in database it should enter as:

```
Monika in one row
Ritu in second row
Archana in thid row
```

Hope you understood my problem.

The textarea i have used is

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: What have you come up with so far? What are you having difficulties with?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the separate values from the textarea using the [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) method. For example, if you had the following TextBox in your .aspx page:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
```

You can then get the values into a string array in code-behind using:

```
string[] values = String.Split(TextBox1.Text, ',');

foreach (string name in values)
{
   InsertRow(name.Trim()); // Substitute for your database insert method
}
```

NB. The Trim() method removes leading and trailing whitespace, which you would get if you had spaces between the commas.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps.

1-  Handle the key press event of the text area using javascript.

2-  In the key press event check if the key press in enter by checking the key code.

3-  Use Ajax or do postback to execute an event at the server side.

4-  Get the value of the text area at server side and split the string on the basis of ‘,” you will get an array of different value.

5-  Save those values on database one by one by iterating the array or simply form a XML document containing all the values and pass it to database and at the database level insert the values  from the XML document.